# Simultanious eigenstate of Hubbard Hamiltonian and Spin operator in two-site model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

Known fact

1. If two operators $A$ and $B$ commute, $[A,B]=0$, they have simultaneous eigenstates. That means $A|a,b\rangle=a|a,b\rangle$ and $B|a,b\rangle=b|a,b\rangle$.
2. Hubbard Hamiltonian $H_\text{hub}$ is symmetric w.r.t. SU(2) spin operators. Thus $[H,S^z]=[H,\vec{S}^2]=0$.

$\Rightarrow$ Thus, eigenstates of $H_\text{hub}$ are also eigenstates of $\vec{S}^2$.

To verify the above conclusion, I set a two-site Hubbard model with one $\uparrow$ and one $\downarrow$ fermions.
$$H=-t\sum_{\sigma=\uparrow,\downarrow}(c^\dagger_{1\sigma}c_{2\sigma}+h.c.)+U\sum_{i=1,2}(n_{i\uparrow} n_{i,\downarrow})$$
Without interaction, the ground state of the Hamiltonian is given by 
$$|g\rangle=\frac{1}{2}(|\uparrow\downarrow ,0\rangle+|\uparrow,\downarrow\rangle+|\downarrow,\uparrow\rangle+|0,\uparrow\downarrow\rangle)$$
The total spin operator $\vec{S}^2$ is written in fermionic operator as 
$$\vec{S}^2=\frac{1}{2}(S^+ S^- + S^- S^+)+(S^z)^2\\=\sum_{i=1,2}\sum_{j=1,2}[\frac{1}{2}(S_i^+ S_j^- + S_i^- S_j^+)+S_i^z S_j^z]$$
where each local operators are
$$
S^+_i=c^\dagger_{i,\uparrow} c_{i,\downarrow}\\
S^-_i=c^\dagger_{i,\downarrow} c_{i,\uparrow}\\
S^z_i=\frac{1}{2}(c^\dagger_{i,\uparrow} c_{i,\uparrow}-c^\dagger_{i,\downarrow} c_{i,\downarrow})
$$
Since $|g\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $H$, so it must be an eigenstate of $\vec{S}^2$. However, for each basis, we have
$$\vec{S}^2|\uparrow\downarrow,0\rangle=0\\
\vec{S}^2|\uparrow,\downarrow\rangle=|\uparrow,\downarrow\rangle+|\downarrow,\uparrow\rangle\\
\vec{S}^2|\downarrow,\uparrow\rangle=|\uparrow,\downarrow\rangle+|\downarrow,\uparrow\rangle\\
\vec{S}^2|0,\uparrow\downarrow\rangle=0$$ 
Thus we have
$$\vec{S}^2|g\rangle=|\uparrow,\downarrow\rangle+|\downarrow,\uparrow\rangle\\
\neq j(j+1)|g\rangle
$$

Where does the contradiction come from?

Comment: While I don't *think* this is the source of your problem, it is worth noting that it is not true that if 2 operators commute then all eigenstates of one are eigenstates of the other. It is instead true that there exists a basis of mutual eignestates for the 2 operators, but this is a weaker statement. For example if I have 2 states $|a,b\rangle$ and $|a,b'\rangle$ with $b\ne b'$ then $|a,b\rangle + |a,b'\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $A$ but not $B$. This is possible due to the degeneracy of the eigenvalue $a$.

Comment: You are right for the degenerated case. However, the ground state of the two-site Hubbard model is non-degenerated. Such a non-degenerate state can be also the case that you mensioned?

Comment: Are you sure about the results you give for $\vec{S}^2$ on the basis vectors? For example, on $| \uparrow \downarrow, 0 \rangle$ I would expect there to be terms arising from $s_1^z s_1^z$ and $s_1^- s_2^+$.

Comment: That terms cannot operate on $|\uparrow\downarrow,0\rangle$, Keep in mind that the state is composed with not just spins but spinful 'fermion'. Each spin operators can operate only singly occupied sites.

Comment: Also, I've solved this problem by considering the properties of fermionic operator. It originated from my simple misunderstood